# JpGraph pie chart slice color not work

Tags: pie-chart, jpgraph

I used a JpGraph in php. Everything ok but slice ($p1->SetSliceColors($color);) color not work. It all time default color.
Here is my used code. Please help me :

```
    $data    = array('40','50', '10');
    $Legends = array('Loss','Win',  'Draw');
    $labels  = array("Loss\n(%.1f%%)","Win\n(%.1f%%)","Draw\n(%.1f%%)");
    $color   = array('red','red','red');
    $graph   = new PieGraph(550,350);
    $graph->SetShadow();

    $p1 = new PiePlot3D($data);
    $p1->ExplodeSlice(1);
    $p1->SetCenter(0.55);
    $p1->SetLegends($Legends);
    $graph->legend->Pos(0.5,0.1);


    $p1->SetTheme("earth");
    $p1->SetSliceColors($color);

    // Setup the labels to be displayed
    $p1->SetLabels($labels);
    $p1->SetLabelPos(1);
    $p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_PER);
    $p1->value->Show();
    $p1->value->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_NORMAL,9);
    $p1->value->SetColor('navy');

    $graph->Add($p1);
    $graph->Stroke();
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Call the Add method before setting colors:

```
$p1 = new PiePlot3D($data);
$graph->Add($p1);
```

[Changing the display settings of line/bar graphs](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
 $graph   = new PieGraph(550,350);
 $graph->ClearTheme();
```

Leave out

```
 $p1->SetTheme("earth");
```

SetSliceColors worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code:
Select the theme that  you want to select, there are several options

```
    $theme_class = new VividTheme;
    $graph = new PieGraph(1000,300);//create the graph
    $graph->ClearTheme();//clean
    $graph->SetTheme($theme_class);//set the theme
```

Now you can see the result, you can see the different themes here:

https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch28.html

[screen shoot of themplates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ejhJ.png)

Other option is clean the theme, something like this

```
    $graph = new PieGraph(1000,300);//create the graph
    $graph->ClearTheme();//clean the theme
    $colors = array('#336699', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00');//put color the colors that you want
    $p1->SetSliceColors($colors);///set the colors
```